# How can I get a new value for a same key in Map

Tags: javascript

```
let sashimiPerMonth = [
  6737, 7244, 5776, 9826, 7057, 9247, 5842, 5484, 6543, 5153, 6832, 8274,
];
let months = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
];

let years = [
  2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,
];
let tempVal = 0
let dataMonth = [];
let dataYear = {};
const yearMap = new Map();
const monthMap = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    let totalSashimi = sashimiPerMonth[i] + tempVal;
    dataMonth.push(totalSashimi);
    tempVal = tempVal + sashimiPerMonth[i];
    monthMap.set(months[i], dataMonth);
  }
  yearMap.set(years[i], monthMap.set(months[i], dataMonth));
}
console.log(yearMap);
console.log(dataYear);
```

I have this arrays. and would like to create a map where the key would be the year and value is another map where the key is the months and the value is the sum of sahimi eaten.
sample output should be (2010: January: 6737) (2010: February: 6737+7244) etc. (2011 : January: total of 2010 + 6737)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For years `for ... of` loop can be used instead of `for` loop.

For months array you can use `for ... in` loop to iterate, because you need to use elements number in array to slice `sashimiPerMonth` array accordingly, which you should `parseInt()` from string.

You can use `reduce()` array method to get sum for current month.

**Code:**

```
let sashimiPerMonth = [
    6737, 7244, 5776, 9826, 7057, 9247, 5842, 5484, 6543, 5153, 6832, 8274,
];
let months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
];

let years = [
    2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021,
];

let previousYearsSashimi = 0;
const yearsMap = new Map();
for (const year of years) {
    const monthsMap = new Map()
    for (const month in months) {
        let sliceMonth = parseInt(month) + 1;
        let currentMonthSashimi = sashimiPerMonth.slice(0, sliceMonth);
        currentMonthSashimi = currentMonthSashimi.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, previousYearsSashimi)
        
        monthsMap.set(months[month], currentMonthSashimi);
    }
    previousYearsSashimi = monthsMap.get('December');
    yearsMap.set(year, monthsMap);
}

console.log(yearsMap);
```

**Output:**

```
Map(12) {
  2010 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 6737,
    'February' => 13981,
    'March' => 19757,
    'April' => 29583,
    'May' => 36640,
    'June' => 45887,
    'July' => 51729,
    'August' => 57213,
    'September' => 63756,
    'October' => 68909,
    'November' => 75741,
    'December' => 84015
  },
  2011 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 90752,
    'February' => 97996,
    'March' => 103772,
    'April' => 113598,
    'May' => 120655,
    'June' => 129902,
    'July' => 135744,
    'August' => 141228,
    'September' => 147771,
    'October' => 152924,
    'November' => 159756,
    'December' => 168030
  },
  2012 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 174767,
    'February' => 182011,
    'March' => 187787,
    'April' => 197613,
    'May' => 204670,
    'June' => 213917,
    'July' => 219759,
    'August' => 225243,
    'September' => 231786,
    'October' => 236939,
    'November' => 243771,
    'December' => 252045
  },
  2013 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 258782,
    'February' => 266026,
    'March' => 271802,
    'April' => 281628,
    'May' => 288685,
    'June' => 297932,
    'July' => 303774,
    'August' => 309258,
    'September' => 315801,
    'October' => 320954,
    'November' => 327786,
    'December' => 336060
  },
  2014 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 342797,
    'February' => 350041,
    'March' => 355817,
    'April' => 365643,
    'May' => 372700,
    'June' => 381947,
    'July' => 387789,
    'August' => 393273,
    'September' => 399816,
    'October' => 404969,
    'November' => 411801,
    'December' => 420075
  },
  2015 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 426812,
    'February' => 434056,
    'March' => 439832,
    'April' => 449658,
    'May' => 456715,
    'June' => 465962,
    'July' => 471804,
    'August' => 477288,
    'September' => 483831,
    'October' => 488984,
    'November' => 495816,
    'December' => 504090
  },
  2016 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 510827,
    'February' => 518071,
    'March' => 523847,
    'April' => 533673,
    'May' => 540730,
    'June' => 549977,
    'July' => 555819,
    'August' => 561303,
    'September' => 567846,
    'October' => 572999,
    'November' => 579831,
    'December' => 588105
  },
  2017 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 594842,
    'February' => 602086,
    'March' => 607862,
    'April' => 617688,
    'May' => 624745,
    'June' => 633992,
    'July' => 639834,
    'August' => 645318,
    'September' => 651861,
    'October' => 657014,
    'November' => 663846,
    'December' => 672120
  },
  2018 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 678857,
    'February' => 686101,
    'March' => 691877,
    'April' => 701703,
    'May' => 708760,
    'June' => 718007,
    'July' => 723849,
    'August' => 729333,
    'September' => 735876,
    'October' => 741029,
    'November' => 747861,
    'December' => 756135
  },
  2019 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 762872,
    'February' => 770116,
    'March' => 775892,
    'April' => 785718,
    'May' => 792775,
    'June' => 802022,
    'July' => 807864,
    'August' => 813348,
    'September' => 819891,
    'October' => 825044,
    'November' => 831876,
    'December' => 840150
  },
  2020 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 846887,
    'February' => 854131,
    'March' => 859907,
    'April' => 869733,
    'May' => 876790,
    'June' => 886037,
    'July' => 891879,
    'August' => 897363,
    'September' => 903906,
    'October' => 909059,
    'November' => 915891,
    'December' => 924165
  },
  2021 => Map(12) {
    'January' => 930902,
    'February' => 938146,
    'March' => 943922,
    'April' => 953748,
    'May' => 960805,
    'June' => 970052,
    'July' => 975894,
    'August' => 981378,
    'September' => 987921,
    'October' => 993074,
    'November' => 999906,
    'December' => 1008180
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Much better understanding from your explanation <3

Comment: Please, edit the title of your question so it's more general and descriptive. And mark the answer as a solution if you liked it. Cheers 

Comment: Sure! But I'm not really sure what to put on the title.